# How to cover an area using bing map?

Tags: php, bing-maps

Is there any possible way to cover a area using BING MAP.

Go to this link.

https://www.movinghelp.com/coverage.aspx?id=5924

I need exactly what it looks like.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks n advance.

Comment: I get "Please change your web browser settings" in Chrome, IE8, Firefox and Safari

Comment: scott, Why can't you try the above new URL

Comment: The url above worked for me in Firefox.

Comment: Anybody just help me get out of this issue...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Bing Maps SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/). You have to create an instance of the VEMap class centered in your interest area, and then create one or more instances of VEShape and add them to the map. The following code creates a shape covering the extent of India:

```
//Create map
    map = new VEMap('myMap');
//Set center and zoom level
    map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(22.268764039073965, 79.98046875),4);

//Create shape (area) with TL, TR, BR and BL coordinates
    var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polygon,
                            [new VELatLong(32.84267363195431, 68.02734375),
                            new VELatLong(32.84267363195431,90.87890625),
                            new VELatLong(4.915832801313164,90.87890625),
                            new VELatLong(4.915832801313164,68.02734375)]);
//Format shape if needed
    var fillColor = new VEColor(226, 224, 219,0.5);
    shape.SetFillColor(fillColor);

//Add shape to map
    map.AddShape(shape);
```

Check the examples shown [here](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/) for further details

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you create an instance of the [Shapelayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412413.aspx) class. Of course you need a [Bing Maps API account](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/) and the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx) and I don't know if those are easy to get.